# Can a Page Source include JavaScript contents?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to view whole content of javascript file in a normal page source?
My javascipt file consists of many links which i want to be visible when i do a normal page source? can anyone please suggest a way how i could achieve it?

Comment: How is viewing the page source relevant for anything?

Comment: Viewing page source should have active links in the code to the source of embedded scripts. You can view scripts in developer consoles like Firebug, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one, you can just embed the script in the page.

Instead of `<script src="abc.js"></script>`, do:

```
<script>
//Full contents of abc.js here
</script>
```

I don't see why you'd want to do that, though. Most developer tools are sufficiently advanced that you get a list of included scripts to inspect on the side (for example, the "sources" tab in the Chrome dev tools)

Comment: Any 1 has any idea about how the google indexes links? does it index static links only or dynamic links also? i.e if my links are in a javascript file which is getting called from some other file, will google index it ?

Comment: @user2260287:Generally there are active links when you view page source :/

Comment: Basically i want to post a link on a different website. ALong with that i want to dynamically control those links through javascript. Means is i want to change or add links i don't have to worry the other site owners. Also i want  those links to be shown up in a normal page source. Is there a way?